# Grouping continuous number as "from~to" strings in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I have an array with numbers.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10];
```

and I'd like to group them into a string with a `from~to` format until the next value is not continuous with the previous value, like the following example.

```
var outputArray = ["1~3", "5", "8~10"];
```

How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @ScottSauyet [the self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503602/)

Comment: @VLAZ: Oh, missed that it was the same person.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sorry for making you confused, I'm not a native speaker and don't know how to start a self-answer question, so I end it with `How to do that` sounds like I was begging for an answer.

Comment: @YamiOdymel: It's not a problem.  It's fairly uncommon to see a self-answer like this, but there are other examples.  I simply didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a slightly shorter approach by using the index to check if the first element needs an new array or if the value is not in order.

For the second mapping, you could just join all elements.

```js
function group(numbers) {
    return numbers
        .reduce((result, value, index, array) => {
            if (!index || array[index - 1] + 1 !== value) {
                result.push([value]);
            } else {
                result[result.length - 1][1] = value;
            }
            return result;
        }, [])
        .map(array => array.join('~'));
}

console.log(group([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `Array.reduce()` followed by `Array.map()`:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10]

const res = nums.reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
    if (idx === 0 || cur - 1 > arr[idx - 1]) {
        acc.push([cur])
    } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur)
    }
    return acc
}, []).map(cur => cur.length > 1 ? cur.shift() + "~" + cur.pop() : cur[0])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go thru only one time all elements. Whenever there is pattern of numbers not in sequence, just put them in results array.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10];

let start = myArray[0];
let end = myArray[0];
const results = [];

for (let i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray[i] === (end + 1)) {
    end = myArray[i];
  } else {
    results.push((start === end) ? `${start}` : `${start}~${end}`);
    start = myArray[i];
    end = myArray[i];
  }
}
results.push((start === end) ? `${start}` : `${start}~${end}`);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for CodePen](https://codepen.io/YamiOdymel/pen/oNgexBV) (or a [Chinese（中文）version](https://codepen.io/YamiOdymel/pen/WNbEwwG)).

Basically just create a `lastValue` variable, and iterating the array. If the `currentValue - 1` equals the `lastValue` then it's a continuous number. Create a new group once the condition failed.

In the final you just merge the groups with a string.

```js
var newArray = [];
var tempArray = []; 
var oldArray = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10];
var lastValue = null;

oldArray.forEach(value => {
  if (lastValue != value - 1 || lastValue === null) {
    tempArray.push([value, value]);
  } else {
    tempArray[tempArray.length - 1][1] = value;
  }
  lastValue = value;
});

tempArray.forEach(value => {
  if (value[0] === value[1]) {
    newArray.push(value[0].toString());
  } else {
    newArray.push(value.join("~"));
  }
});

// OUTPUS: (3) ["1~3", "5", "8~10"]
document.write(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

For typescript, this function takes a sorted array of numbers and groups them into a single string.

```
function convertNumberArrayToRangeString(numbers: number[]): string {
    const delimiter = '~';
    return numbers
      .reduce((accumulator: string, currentValue: number, index: number, array: number[]) => {
        if (index > 0 && array[index - 1] + 1 !== currentValue) {
            if (index > 2 && array[index - 1] - array[index - 2] === 1) {
              accumulator +=  delimiter + array[index - 1].toString();
            }
            accumulator += ',' + currentValue.toString();
        } else if (index === 0 || index === array.length - 1) { // first or last
          if (array[index - 1] === currentValue - 1) {
            accumulator +=  delimiter;
          } else if (index > 0) {
            accumulator +=  ',';
          }
          accumulator += currentValue.toString();
        } 
        return accumulator;
      }, '');
  }

const list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]; // sorted unique list
const groupedList = convertNumberArrayToRangeString(list);
console.log(groupedList);
```

Output> "1~3,6~8"